# yii2: undefined variable defined within foreach

Tags: php, yii2

I have this query in my view.php

```
<?php
    $packageq= Yii::$app->db->createCommand
         ("SELECT p.package_name,p.`total_charges` 
          as 'package_charges'
          FROM `package` p, estimate e,patient_detail pd 
          where pd.package=p.id 
          and e.ipd_patient_id=pd.ipd_patient_id 
          and e.id=$model->id");
    $packages= $packageq->queryAll();
    //var_dump($packages);exit;
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'; 
    echo "<tr><th>Package Name</th><th>Amount</th></tr>"; 
    if (![$packages]==''){
    foreach($packages as $package){
     echo "<tr><td>";  
     echo $package['package_name'];
     echo "</td><td>";  
     $d= $package['package_charges'];
     echo $d;

      echo "</td></tr>"; 
    }
    }else{
        $d=0;
    }
    var_dump($d);exit;
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo 'Total D';
    echo "</td><td>"; 

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo 'Total A+B+C+D';
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo ($a+$b+$c+$d);
    echo "</table>";  
    ?>
```

When I am doing a var_dump for $packages, I am getting

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

When I am doing a var_dump for $d I am getting the error
**variable d is not defined**
any specific reason for this or I am doing anything wrong here.
Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regard to `$packages`, `$packageq->queryAll()` must not be returning anything.  Regarding $d, you are dumping it outside of the scope within which `$d` is defined.  $d must be defined outside of the if/else if you want to be able to access $d in the scope where you have the var_dump.  If you declare $d outside of the if/else with `$d;` or define `$d` as some empty value (e.g. `$d = 0;`), you'll be able to set it within the if/else and still have access to it in the parent scope.  If you defined `$d = 0` before the condition you could drop the `else { $d = 0; }` all together.

Also, if $packages is an array and you want to test if it populated, you might consider

```
if(!empty($packages)) {
    ...
}
```

Instead of

```
if(![$packages] == '') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @superultranova. I actually forget using `if(!empty)` . Thank you so much. and your suggestion of putting $d before the condition once also works fine.